# How to get the background image to cover the entire page in Jasper reports Table of Contents?

Tags: jasper-reports, tableofcontents

My Jasper report's table of contents works fine. But I am not able to get the background image to cover the entire page since it is not allowing to declare the band height of the background tag to the complete page height (842 px). (Other text elements in the pageHeader, detail and pageFooter tag declare their band heights as well.)

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="TocReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"
              leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="2d2696e4-c268-49e6-88d8-64a44e147b2c">

<background>
        <band height="610">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="610"  mode="Transparent" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{backgroundImage1}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
</background>
```

Please help.

Comment: Because you have margins... remove those.. and you will be able to use full height.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, I already have all margins set to "0". Edited the question to add this part of the jrxml as well. The problem is the TOC has other bands already, which have heights set.